# Blazor Templates/layouts, including different javascript libraries to different templates/layouts

Tags: css, templates, layout, blazor

Blazor Server .Net5

I'm porting a web template to Blazor, keeping the Css and Jquery for styling purposes. Everything is working great, however.

I have a login, Registration and forgotten password page that requires no javascript plugins.
The rest of the site, has loads of javascript links relevant to numerous plugins etc that are not needed on these pages.

Is it possible to include different library links to different razor layouts so I can use 1 layout for the site and another for the login/reg/password page......... or is it possible to create a razor layout that uses a different _hosts.cshtml file, so that I can include the library links in the new _hosts.cshtml instead?

I don't want to rewrite the entire template from scratch to accommodate what I would have assumed is a simple ask. I also don't mind the obvious postback from login/reg/password pages going to the main site.

I've checked many sites and tutorials and nothing has proven useful.

Comment: Checkout css isolation bundling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I've mistakenly put the emphasis on Css to make the question easier to answer, thinking the answer would be relevant to jquery and bootstrap libraries. Thanks for the link. I'll change the question to be more javascript library based.